# react router link with material ui button submit

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am using flask on the backend and react, react router and material-ui as a frontend.

I have:

- material-ui/core 3.4.0,
- react router dom 4.3.1

I am trying to create simple sign up form. 
I would like to submit the form's data and then redirect to the index page using react router. 
My problem is that material-ui button does not work with the link from router. 
Is it possible to combine this two together somehow?

My code:

import:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { withStyles, Grid, Paper, Avatar, Typography, Button, TextField} from '@material-ui/core'
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined'
```

and render return:

```
render() {
  const { classes } = this.props
  const { user: { username, password } } = this.state
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>

        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockIcon />
        </Avatar>

        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign up
        </Typography>

        <form onSubmit={this.saveUser}>
          <TextField label="Username" value={username} onChange={this.handleChange('username')} margin="normal" required fullWidth/>
          <TextField label="Password" value={password} onChange={this.handleChange('password')} margin="normal" required fullWidth type='password'/>

          <Button component={Link} to="/" type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">Sign Up</Button>

        </form>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

When I remove from Button *component={Link} to="/"*:

```
<Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">Sign Up</Button>
```

then submit work and saves data in database. When I remove *type="submit"*:

```
<Button component={Link} to="/" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">Sign Up</Button>
```

then redirect to index page.

Can I combine somehow this two in one button?

*RaisedButton, FlatButton* from *material-ui* not working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to state:

```
doRedirect: false
```

In render():

```
<Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">Sign Up</Button>
```

In submit hanler:

```
saveUser = () => {
    // **********
    // Your code to update database
    // **********

    this.setState({ doRedirect: true });
}
```

In render():

```
{ this.state.doRedirect && <Redirect to="/" /> }
```

And of course:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: I'm not sure where put this line: { this.state.doRedirect && <Redirect to="/" /> } in my code? I'm still a little beginner, so I would be grateful if you could help me with this one too? I understand the rest of the parts.

Comment: eg:
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
 { this.state.doRedirect && <Redirect to="/" /> }
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>

Answer (score 0):

In your save user function just redirect after saving the user.
you can get history from props

```
saveUser = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  //update database with user
  this.props.history.location.push('new-route')
  // or you can use window.location
  window.location.href = 'new-route'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <Button
          onClick={() => {}}
          variant="outlined"
          component={Link}
          to={{
            pathname: `/`,
            search: location.search,
          }}
        >
          Submit
 </Button>
```

Comment: This redirects synchronously on click, but the author asked for a redirect after an asynchronous event